# Does getdeb change applications that do not need it?

Tags: apt, repository, official-repositories

There is an application I really want to install (RubyRipper), which seems to only be possible in a way visible to apt by using getdeb. However, I don't want new (and possibly less stable) versions of my existing applications.

For example, I wouldn't want firefox replaced with a version other than that available from the default Ubuntu repository. Same thing with any other application: vlc, texstudio, libre office, etc.

Would using getdeb cause my existing applications to be updated from different repositories? (According to my research, this seems to be the case). If so, can I make getdeb only act as a repository for applications not available elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would using getdeb cause my existing applications to be updated from different repositories?

Yes, potentially, if Getdeb offers a newer version of something than what is in the official repositories, apt may install that newer version when you do an update. (Be default, Ubuntu will use the newest version of packages).

If you use `apt-get install` in a terminal to install / update things (instead of the GUI), it will always tell you what it's going to do, before it does anything, so you can be sure.

You could either download the .deb file yourself, and install that, or add the Getdeb repository, install the package you want, and then disable the Getdeb repository afterwards.

There's also [a PPA for RubyRipper](https://launchpad.net/~brandonsnider/+archive/ubuntu/ruby-ripper), which I think would be a better choice (more up to date, contains only that package, directly from the author). Note that neither Getdeb nor the PPA have builds for the latest versions of Ubuntu, and the PPA says:

> Development has slowed down considerably at the time I'm writing this. The best current way to rip audio is Morituri, which is available in Precise and beyond.

so maybe there are other options for ripping audio ?

Comment: It does appear RubyRipper is not actively developed anymore. Morituri is not in the 16.04 repositories, but hopefully that will change. At any rate, getting Morituri to work does seem to be the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: @Kyle, There's also plenty of other nice CD ripping tools.

Comment: Ya, but I am kind of a perfectionist, and it does not seem that there is anything else close to EAC in terms of precision.

Comment: I need to purge Getdeb... but before I need to check dependences... How check if I am using getdeb at UBUNTU 16 LTS?